# Graphs, vertices, STL lists: Why does list come out empty?

Tags: c++

I posted this question earlier but badly worded which is why it got bad reactions. I will try to be clear in what I am asking. Please comment if you do not understand my question. I am using two lists, one to hold vertices, and another to hold the neighbors of each vertex. When I create a vertex, I push it into the first list. When I want to create edges, I find the vertex in my 'keys' list and add the neighboring vertex into its 'neighbor' list. I repeat for all edges. However, my neighbor list always comes out empty. I check if it did push the vertex into the neighbor list with a print statement in the addEdge function, which shows that it does go in. The neighbor list always come up empty when I try to access them later. Why does that happen? Why does the second list always come empty? Is the memory not preserved?

Eg:
Create vertex 1, 2, 3 [stored in keys list]

Create edge: 1-1, 1-2 (2-1), 1-3 (3-1 [stored in neighbor list]

Find edges of 1: nothing is found (why?)

My implementation. The graph class holds the keys list, the vertex holds the neighbor list. The functions that I use to add edges are named: addEdge in both classes. The main also prints that the vertices have no neighbors.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @Happy Code runs without error. The debugger closes by itself. I am using VS 2013 if it helps.

Comment: @mdislam - The debugger allows you to run the program a single step at a time, set breakpoints, watch variables, etc.  It isn't there just to "run the program without error".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Right. I haven't used the debugger too much which is why I forgot about that. Where do you suggest I put the breakpoints?

Comment: @mdislam - Did you write the program?  If you did, then you had a plan in mind before writing the program.  Therefore, run your program a single step at a time until you see the program diverging from the plan you have.  That is how you determine where to place breakpoints.  BTW, there is no way that you can write a non-trivial program as you wrote and *not* have usage of the debugger as part of your tools.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've only touched the debugger when I ran into segfaults. I will need to devote a day to do what you described, starting now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I may be doing this wrong, so please feel free to yell at me. I tried pinpointing where I thought it was going wrong, which is vertex::printNeighbors. I put a breakpoint at the start of the function, and I get the follow errors: http://i.imgur.com/JQ5Qkf0.png Is this just because of the breakpoint or something else? Also, when I put the breakpoint on the next line, the neighbors list's size is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The central issue is that you are passing around values, modifying copies of them and expecting the original to be modified as well. In particular, the issues are

1. You want `getV` to return a non-const reference to a `vertex<T>`. Note that the name `get` is usually associated with a `const` method that doesn't affect the object. So, you might want to change the name a bit.
2. In `graph::addEdge`, `sKey` and `dKey` should really be `vertex<T>&`. Also, when you call `addEdge` on `sKey` and `dKey`, pass in the entire `vertex<T>` object that you want to add, instead of the object of type `T`. The code, as it stands, compiles because `T` can be implicitly converted to `vertex<T>` but that isn't what you want.
3. Lastly, why are you maintaining a list of `vertex<T>`s in `vertex`? Change it to a `list<vertex<T>*>`s. Note that if you end up changing the data structure in `graph` from `list` to something else that could invalidate iterators and pointers to its elements, this approach will fail.

Comment: 1. I will fix this once I get the other part done.
2. I passed in the object, my mind must have lapsed when I was coding that bit. 
3.I think using pointers may be an issue since my professor is not lenient on what I use.

Comment: Now that I think about [1], I realize I should be returning references to the vertex in the keys list rather than a regular vertex. Or would a vertex* be better?

Comment: Yay! The biggest help in your comment was that I was modifying copies rather than the original. I used iterators to solve the issue. Now I can actually find the neighbors. Thanks. Off to figure out how to code DFS!!